# Pointer to Arrays

Tags: c

i am using a pointer to an array of 4 integers as int(*ptr)[4]

using the following code in which m pointing to a 2-D array using this pointer

```
int arr[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};

int (*ptr)[4]= arr[4];

int m= (*ptr)[2];
```

what will be the value in "m"...

i need to find the value of element arr[1][2] how can i get it using pointer ptr?

Comment: Format your code next time.  Is this a homework question?  Tag it that way if it is, and tell us what you've tried and what your exact problem is.

Comment: Also, what's stopping you from running it and trying (it won't work, by the way).

Comment: On the second line 'arr[4]' isn't that an index out of range? The max size of arr has been declared as 3. So the maximum index should be 2 as it is zero-based.

Comment: make ir arr[2] even then its not giving the correct output...

Comment: ptr= arr[2] gives an error.. why???

Comment: What is your VALID declaration for ptr? It sure isn't int (*ptr)[4].

Comment: it is this only...
ptr is a pointer to an array of 4 integers...

Comment: @nitinpuri, I'll give you a hint. You cannot declare a single pointer in C that will, after one assignment, traverse the different levels of indirection of multi-dimensional arrays by simple incrementing or dereferencing. To achieve complete traversal, you need a one dimensional array of pointers, with each value initialized to point at each section of the pointed-at 2 dimensional array.

Comment: tell me one thing... i have this ptr pointing to an array of 4 integers...
i get it pointing to a 2 d array with 4 columns...
now suppose for a particular row i need to find out 3rd column of that row... if ptr is pointing to the base address of that row... will int m=(*ptr)[2] point to the value of 3rd element or what is the expression needed?

Answer (score 1):

Multi-dimensional arrays are really one dimensional arrays with a little syntaxic sugar.
The initialization you had for ptr wasn't an address. It should have been

```
int *ptr[4] = { &arr[0][0], &arr[1][0], &arr[2][0], &arr[3][0]};
```

You can also leave the 4 out and just use

```
int *ptr[] = { &arr[0][0], &arr[1][0], &arr[2][0], &arr[3][0]};
```

I made a few modifications to your code below. Note the two sections with the printf. They should help to demonstrative how the values are actually laid out in memory.

```
#define MAJOR 3
#define MINOR 4
int arr[MAJOR][MINOR]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};

int (*ptr)[4];
int *p = &arr[0][0];

// init ptr to point to starting location in arr
for(i = 0; i < MAJOR; i++) {
    ptr[i] = &arr[i][0];
}

// print out all the values of arr using a single int *
for(i = 0; i < MAJOR * MINOR; i++) {
    printf(" %d", *(p + i) );
}

for(i = 0; i < MAJOR; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < MINOR; j++) {
     printf( " %d", *(p + i * MAJOR + j) );
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ptr doesn't point to anything and probably doesn't even compile, since [4] is outside the bounds of either the [3] or the [4] of the original array.

If you need to find arr[1][2] then you need int (*ptr)[4] = arr[1]; int m = ptr[2];

Comment: `int (*ptr)[4] = &arr[1]; int m = (*ptr)[2];` Note the extra `&` and `*`. Your variant will not even compile.

Comment: hey anDrey tell me one thing
int (*ptr)[4]= &arr[4] will be out of bound?

Comment: @nitinpuri, yes it will be out of bounds - `arr` only has 3 elements, so the maximum index is 2.

Comment: arr was declared with the size [3] and [4]. With only one index it refers to the first size [3]. Since arrays in C/C++ are zero based the maximum value allowed there would be 2. And to clarify what DeadMG refers to, you need to use the '&' to get the reference of arr at the specified index.

Comment: first part is done but int m= (*ptr)[2] does not point to element 3 of 4 element array..

Answer (score 0):

The are multiple ways of accessing the value of element `arr[1][2]`.

The method used in the code below is called pointer to pointer. By storing the address of the first element of `pa[]` in `pb`, one can use `pb` to access elements of `aa[][]`. One can use array notation `aa[1][2]`, or one can use pointer notation `*((*pb+1)+2)`. Both the notation approaches yield equivalent results.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int aa[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
 int *pa[3];

 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 pa[i]=aa[i];
 pb=pa;

 printf("pb[1][2]=%d\n",pb[1][2]); /*Array Notation*/
 printf("arr[1][2]=%d",*(*(pb+1)+2)); /*Pointer Notation*/
}
```